# Access private data member of class from unrelated class in C++ converter constructor

Tags: c++, casting

In the code given below, to access private data member of B we can use member function of class B and return the data member, assign that to the data member of A within the constructor (converter function). But I am unable to do so. Please suggest some help. Other way can be making Class A friend of B but there is need for accessing by constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class B
{
    int i_;
    public:
        B(int i = 3) : i_(i) {}
        int give() { return i_; }
};
class A
{
   int i_;
   public:
        A(int i = 0) : i_(i) { cout << "A::A(i)\n"; }
        A(const B &b1) : i_(b1.i_) {} // Type casting using constructor
        int display() { cout << i_; }
};
int main()
{
   A a;
   B b; // object is constructed
   a = static_cast<A>(b); // B::operator A(), converting data member of class B to class A
   a.display();
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough to follow @StoryTeller's advice, you also need to change constructor of A to use proper 'getter' method so that you stop accessing private member:

`A(const B &b1) : i_(b1.give()) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is const correctness. `int give()` is a non-const member function, which can only be called on non-const objects. However `const B &b1` is a reference to a const object.

Since you don't modify the `B` object when returning the value of the integer, make your code const correct by const qualifying the member function:

```
int give() const { return i_; }
```

And now the `A` c'tor isn't attempting an illegal operation.

Comment: Thanks for useful info. The problem is still this :                           
prog.cpp: In constructor ‘A::A(const B&)’:
prog.cpp:18:32: error: ‘int B::i_’ is private within this context
         A(const B& b1) : i_(b1.i_) {  } // Type casting using constructor
                                ^~
prog.cpp:6:9: note: declared private here
     int i_;
         ^~                                                                                                                    I want to know how to access that i_ of B without friend declaration.

Comment: @KnitahK - This isn't a forum or a debugging service. I pointed out the problem with the code that was obvious.  If you have a *specific* issue, post a [mcve].

Comment: @KnitahK - And that error indicate you aren't using `get()`. So what does your code in the question has to do with the error?

Comment: Sorry for not asking question correctly. I tried using get() function in conversion constructor of A but I think I may not be knowing exact way to do so. That was what I am trying to ask, the correct way to write code. So may you please explain it to me.

Comment: @KnitahK - Your use of a getter is okay. There is no unqualified "best" way. It's highly dependent on various factors. [Pick good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to take you through the various levels of knowing the language. And write a lot of code. This is something only experience can teach.